# Dynamically Change Yii2 configurations

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I am trying to dynamically change App name and some components config Using component event:
Please refer to the attached image, I have highlighted with red marker which part i want to set in my component.

[image]

My component code is following:

```
<?php
namespace common\components;

use Yii;
use common\models\AppPartner;


class Arun Extends \yii\base\Behavior{

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            \yii\web\Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST => 'getAppData',
        ];
    }

    public function getAppData(){
      // want to change stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the application properties like this:

```
\Yii::$app->name = 'new name';
```

The app also gives you access to the components:

```
\Yii::$app->pinPayment->settings['mode'] = 'new mode';
```

See these parts of the documentation:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-application-components

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#$name-detail

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will check this and update for the same